# Странная задача на циклы

Tags: java, while, break

Есть такая [задача](https://practicum.yandex.ru/trainer/java-developer/lesson/82ae081e-e0c6-4a9f-9eb4-4a3d0b1e0c80/task/632e8e73-562f-454e-af83-6bb652cb98a1/):

> Бесконечный цикл while (true) с прерыванием break применяется для
> решения достаточно ограниченного спектра задач. Чаще всего его удобнее
> заменить на цикл while с условием. Потренируйтесь это делать. Эта
> программа с помощью бесконечного цикла суммирует числа, которые вводит
> пользователь. Она работает до тех пор, пока не будет введён 0.
> Перепишите её, заменив бесконечный цикл на цикл while с условием.

**Вот исходный код, который нужно дописать:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Praktikum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0; // Сумма
        int input; // Ввод пользователя

        while (true) {
            input = scanner.nextInt();
            if (input == 0) {
                break;
            }
            sum = sum + input;
        }
        System.out.println("Сумма введённых чисел: " + sum);
    }
}
```

**Вот подсказка к решению:**

> 1. Цикл должен выполняться до тех пор, пока пользователь не введёт 0, то есть значение переменной input не равно нулю. Это и станет его
>    условием input != 0.
> 2. Переменной input нужно присваивать значение перед циклом и внутри него, так как считывать ввод пользователя придётся и там, и там.

**Вот мой код, который компилятор не принимает:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Praktikum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0; // Сумма
        int input; // Ввод пользователя
        
        while (int input != 0) {  
            input = scanner.nextInt();
            sum = sum + input;
        }
        if (int input == 0) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Сумма введённых чисел: " + sum);
    }
}
```

**Компилятор выдаёт следующее:**

> Вывод Ошибка препроцессинга: Не используйте break и while(true) Failed
> compilation

Т.е., если я правильно понимаю, прерывать  цикл с помощью break не разрешается. Но как тогда решить задачу? Или же я неправильно понимаю задание...

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: У вас же брейк вне цикла. И первый ввод нужно до цикла сделать, а внутри поменять порядок

Comment: Сделал так:
    
    class Praktikum {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int sum = 0; // Сумма
            int input; // Ввод пользователя
            input = scanner.nextInt();
            while (int input != 0) {  
                
                sum = sum + input;
                input = scanner.nextInt();
                if (int input == 0) {
                break;
            }

            }
            System.out.println("Сумма введённых чисел: " + sum);
        }
    }

Comment: Вывод
Ошибка препроцессинга:
Не используйте break и while(true)
Failed compilation

Comment: Выложил код здесь: https://fastpic.org/view/117/2022/0511/ec114cb1d765d8b02f67e4027126dda7.jpg

Comment: Код картинкой = отсутствие кода, и наличие картинки :)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков
Просто в комментарий у меня код не вставляется.

Comment: @java Вы можете редактировать свой вопрос и добавить код

Comment: Даже если редактирую, код не добавляется. К тому же там всего 500 символов, так что не получается.

Answer (score 3):

Например так.

```
    while ((input = scanner.nextInt()) != 0) {
        sum = sum + input;
    }
```

Из плюсов - не надо чтение 2 раза писать.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int sum = 0; // Сумма 
 int input; // Ввод пользователя 
 input = scanner.nextInt(); 
 while (input != 0) {
   sum = sum + input;
   input = scanner.nextInt(); 
 } 
 System.out.println("Сумма введённых чисел: " + sum); }
```

Comment: Всё равно не принимает. import java.util.Scanner;

Вывод
Ошибка препроцессинга:
Не используйте break и while(true)
Failed compilation

Comment: Вы не этот код компилируете, здесь нет брейка

Comment: Я компилирую код без брейка, ведь его нельзя использовать. Я ваш код использую, который вы привели в первом вашем примере. Только             input = scanner.nextInt();  и 
            sum = sum + input; местами поменял.

Comment: Но если в коде нет брейка, почему препроцессор о нём говорит? Я код раньше не приводил.В коде из вашего коммента брейк есть.Вот конкретно код из этого ответа вы компилировали?

Comment: Вчера не проходило, а сегодня это решение прошло... Спасибо за помощь! Просто уже ночью делал задачу, видимо мозг отключился. На свежую голову скопировал код правильно. Ещё раз большое спасибо !

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Praktikum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0; // Сумма
        int input = scanner.nextInt(); //  <- 2. Переменной input нужно присваивать значение перед циклом и внутри него, так как считывать ввод пользователя придётся и там, и там.
        
        while (input != 0) {  
            input = scanner.nextInt();  
            sum = sum + input;
        }
        System.out.println("Сумма введённых чисел: " + sum);
        //Далее лишний код.
        //if (int input == 0) {
        //    break;
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за совет. Однако снова Вывод
Ошибка препроцессинга:
Не используйте break и while(true)
Failed compilation

Comment: А что значит эта фраза: "Переменной input нужно присваивать значение перед циклом и внутри него, так как считывать ввод пользователя придётся и там, и там."? Как именно и какие значения присвоить и там, и там?

Comment: Intut это поля которые пользователь ведёт тект!

Comment: Это я понял. input = scanner.nextInt(); - это, как я понимаю и есть присваивание значения.